Implementing an advanced filter on dates for power bi Embedded. I am not able to create the right filter on my BI report
I am currently having a problem with my filtering in an embedded PBI report. I was wondering if someone knows how to fix it.
In my report I would like to implement a filter that looks like this: An Advanced filtering where you can select between two dates with operators 'is on or after''and 'is on or before'.
If I Implement this filter on table 'Zorgactiviteit datum' and column 'Datum', it does not seem to work. The filter in Power BI Embedded is in the code below.
const filter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced",
    target: {
        table: "Zorgactiviteit datum",
        column: "Datum"
    },
    logicalOperator: "And",
    conditions: [
        {
            operator: "IsOrAfter",
            value: new Date().getDate() - 30
        },
        {
            operator: "IsOnOrBefore",
            value: new Date()
        }
    ],
    filterType: models.FilterType.AdvancedFilter
};

try {
    await report.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [filter]);
    console.log("Report filter was added.");
}
catch (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
}

What I already did was:
1: Different operators that are normal for an advanced filter: LessThanOrEqual or GreaterThanOrEqual.
2: I tried the filter on the report and on the page.

Operator using in conditions is incorrect. Please find the supported advancedfilterconditions operations here. Replace your condition operators with GreaterThanOrEqual and LessThanOrEqual what you already tried and it should work.
Could you provide more information if it's date filter or date slicer? You mentioned that you tried from filters in the report page, and it didn't worked. Assuming it as date slicer, we need to setSlicerState of that date Visual. Refer to this RangeSlicer documentation.
Refer to the below code, where we get the target visual and used setSlicerState to filter the report on the dates,
const filter : models.IAdvancedFilter = {
$schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced",
target: {
        table: "Date",
        column: "Date"
    },
    filterType: models.FilterType.Advanced,
    logicalOperator: "And",
    conditions: [
        {
            operator: "GreaterThanOrEqual",
            value: "2014-10-12T21:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            operator: "LessThanOrEqual",
            value: "2014-11-28T22:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
};
try {
   
    const visual = await page.getVisualByName('Visual_Name');

    // Set the slicer state which contains the slicer filters.
    await visual.setSlicerState({ filters: [filter] });
    console.log("Date slicer was set.");
}
catch (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
}



Tnx, it works now!, the issue was the date format.
